# Font Awesome icon does not shownig up

Tags: font-awesome

I would like to use Font Awesome icon in my project. I have included my kit in head section and put one icon into my code. However, it is not showing up, though I used font-weight, font-size, etc.
The icon is there it takes space and grows when I apply width and height, but it is not visible. Attempts to apply color failed, though background-color works well.
What trouble is it?

I have applied CSS rules for color and fonts and expect to see the icon on page.